# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function " jQuery each function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a pretty basic question. I have this block of code which I thought was OK but its throwing up an error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here is the code in question

```
$('.colourbox').each(function(i){
// select visible children
var visibleDivs = $(this).children('div').length;

// use whatever width calculation you'd like...
var targetWidth = 300 / visibleDivs.length - 1;

// apply the width to the divs
visibleDivs.width(targetWidth);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`visibleDivs` is a number :

```
var visibleDivs = $(this).children('div').length;
```

So it doesn't have a `width` function which make this line fail :

```
visibleDivs.width(targetWidth);
```

You probably want

```
$('.colourbox').each(function(i){
   // select visible children
   var visibleDivs = $(this).children('div');

   // use whatever width calculation you'd like...
   var targetWidth = 300 / visibleDivs.length - 1;

   // apply the width to the divs
   visibleDivs.width(targetWidth);
});
```

But you should have solved this issue yourself using [the developer tools of your browser](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) :

1. look at the exact line of the error given in the console
2. if that's not enough, debug and, line after line, look at the value of your variables

Answer (score 0):

Variable `visibleDivs` has a value of a number of child divs.

```
var visibleDivs = $(this).children('div').length;
```

What you probably wan't to have there is a list of child divs instead:

```
var visibleDivs = $(this).children('div');
```

Full example:

```
$('.colourbox').each(function(i){
    // select visible children
    var visibleDivs = $(this).children('div');

    // use whatever width calculation you'd like...
    var targetWidth = 300 / visibleDivs.length - 1;

    // apply the width to the divs
    visibleDivs.width(targetWidth);
});
```